# Doing something than doing other thing or than to do other thing?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> She pulled her toolbox toward her on the table, fishing through it
>   for no other reason **than to keep** her hands busy.

If this sentence use "than doing", does it sound natural?

> ...  fishing through it for no other reason **than keeping** her hands busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a gerund is grammatically correct in this context, but the to-form also conveys a sense of purpose, like "in order to", which is more appropriate as a reason.

According to this [NGRAM graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?smoothing=3&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&content=reason%20than%20to%20keep%2Creason%20than%20keeping&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creason%20than%20to%20keep%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creason%20than%20keeping%3B%2Cc0), "reason than to keep" is about ten times as common as "reason than keeping".

Comment: I'd prefer the first.  The second sounds just a little bit awkward or stilted to my ear.  Other uses of "than" + gerund are more natural, however.  (eg. "There is no higher priority than keeping the children safe."

Comment: @BadZen in your example, the meaning is not "in order to", and that may be what biases in favour of **to keep** in the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it sounds normal. It is used in general texts in numerous newspapers.

[Link showing sources](https://ludwig.guru/s/than+keeping)

Comment: Simply noticing that colocations of "than" and "keeping" occur does not necessarily make it OK in the specific case given!